# Android instrumented test freezes when it tests a suspend function that uses RoomDatabase.withTransaction

Tags: android, testing, android-room, suspend

I'm trying to test the following LocalDataSource function, **NameLocalData.methodThatFreezes** function, but it freezes. How can I solve this? Or How can I test it in another way?

**Class to be tested**

```
class NameLocalData(private val roomDatabase: RoomDatabase) : NameLocalDataSource {

  override suspend fun methodThatFreezes(someParameter: Something): Something {
    roomDatabase.withTransaction {
      try {
        // calling room DAO methods here
      } catch(e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
        // ...
      }
      return something
    }
  }
}
```

**Test class**

```
@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NameLocalDataTest {
  private lateinit var nameLocalData: NameLocalData

  // creates a Room database in memory
  @get:Rule
  var roomDatabaseRule = RoomDatabaseRule()

  @get:Rule
  var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

  @Before
  fun setup() = runBlockingTest {
     initializesSomeData()
     nameLocalData = NameLocalData(roomDatabaseRule.db)
  }

 @Test
 fun methodThatFreezes() = runBlockingTest {
    nameLocalData.methodThatFreezes // test freezes
 }

 // ... others NameLocalDataTest tests where those functions been tested does not use
 // roomDatabase.withTransaction { } 
}
```

**Gradle's files configuration**

```
espresso_version = '3.2.0'
kotlin_coroutines_version = '1.3.3'
room_version = '2.2.5'

test_arch_core_testing = '2.1.0'
test_ext_junit_version = '1.1.1'
test_roboletric = '4.3.1'
test_runner_version = '1.2.0'

androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$test_arch_core_testing"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$test_ext_junit_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$test_runner_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$test_runner_version"
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Last time I wrote a test for Room database I just simply use `runBlock` and it worked for me...
Could you take a look into [this sample](https://github.com/nglauber/books_jetpack/blob/master/data_room/src/androidTest/java/dominando/android/data_room/RoomRepositoryTest.kt) and check if it works for you as well?

Edit:
Ops! I missed this part... I tried this (in the same sample):

1. I defined a dummy function in my DAO using `@Transaction`

```
@Transaction
suspend fun quickInsert(book: Book) {
    save(book)
    delete(book)
}
```

2. I think this is the key of the problem. Add `setTransactionExecutor` to your Database instantiation.

```
appDatabase = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context,
    AppDatabase::class.java
).setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    .build()
```

3. Finally, the test worked using `runBlocking`

```
@Test
fun dummyTest() = runBlocking {
    val dao = appDatabase.bookDao();
    val id = dummyBook.id

    dao.quickInsert(dummyBook)

    val book = dao.bookById(id).first()
    assertNull(book)
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380210/android-instrumentation-test-doesnt-run-to-end-when-using-room-transaction-fun).

Comment: Thanks Glauber! In this case this approach didn't work. I take a look on RoomRepository, there the DAO methods are called outside a **RoomDatabase.withTransaction { } block**. I can make test for the other functions of the DataSource that don't use RoomDatabase.withTransaction { } block with no problems, either using **runBlocking** or **runBlockingTest**. The test freezes when I try to test a function that needs the use of **RoomDatabase.withTransaction { }**.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried many things to make this work, used `runBlockingTest`, used `TestCoroutineScope`, tried `runBlocking`, used `allowMainThreadQueries`, `setTransactionExecutor`, and `setQueryExecutor` on my in memory database.

But nothing worked until I found this [comment thread](https://medium.com/@paulwisner/we-are-unable-to-get-roomdatabase-withtransaction-38fab770378a) in the `Threading models in Coroutines and Android SQLite API` article in the Android Developers Medium blog, other people mentioned running into this. Author Daniel Santiago said:

> I’m not sure what Robolectric might be doing under the hood that could cause withTransaction to never return.
> We usually don’t have Robolectric tests but we have plenty of Android Test examples if you want to try that route: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/integration-tests/kotlintestapp/src/androidTest/java/androidx/room/integration/kotlintestapp/test/SuspendingQueryTest.kt

I was able to fix my test by changing it from a Robolectric test to an AndroidTest and by using `runBlocking`

This is an example from the google source:

```
    @Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun setUp() {
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            TestDatabase::class.java
        )
            .build()
        booksDao = database.booksDao()
    }

    @Test
    fun runSuspendingTransaction() {
        runBlocking {
            database.withTransaction {
                booksDao.insertPublisherSuspend(
                    TestUtil.PUBLISHER.publisherId,
                    TestUtil.PUBLISHER.name
                )
                booksDao.insertBookSuspend(TestUtil.BOOK_1.copy(salesCnt = 0))
                booksDao.insertBookSuspend(TestUtil.BOOK_2)
                booksDao.deleteUnsoldBooks()
            }
            assertThat(booksDao.getBooksSuspend())
                .isEqualTo(listOf(TestUtil.BOOK_2))
        }
    }
```